# Use of Apache Qpid C++ JMS client

Tags: java, c++, apache, jms, qpid

I want to subscribe to a Java Messaging Service (JMS) publish-subscribe service using Apache Qpid. However rather than using Java, I want to use C++. My customer told me this was possible (and even said trivial). Are they correct? Can anyone point me to an example? Everywhere I've looked says that to use JMS I have to use Java. The point here is that the service is a third party service (so I can't change it to use AMQP or any other protocol other than JMS).

Comment: If your customer said it's trivial, maybe he can provide for pointers?

Comment: I suspect my customer may not actually know. Also, want to get independent opinion.

Comment: If you just want to subscribe and drain the messages, please look into **drain** executable in Qpid c++ installation> examples folder. if that suffice, you can use the source of **drain** to implement this. Let me know if this helps, i'll give you full path on how to implement this.

Answer (score 0):

This depends quite a bit on what JMS Broker you are using.  If the broker supports the AMQP 1.0 protocol as well as whatever native protocol it implements for its JMS client then you might be in luck.

The main thing you need besides support for AMQP 1.0 then is good cross protocol communication support such that a message send from the JMS client can get turned into something meaningful for the subscribed AMQP client or the other way round the broker needs to map incoming AMQP messages into meaningful JMS representations so that the two interoperate successfully.

A Broker like ActiveMQ does support this sort of thing along with support for other protocols as well.  You need to have the [AMQP](http://activemq.apache.org/amqp.html) support turned on in the broker and then you can use the C++ client from the [Qpid](http://qpid.apache.org/) project to send messages and receive messages with relative ease.

Comment: the problem is, I have no control over the provider. So are you saying that this can all be done in the client? So far, the provider has rejected sending AMQP over the wire.

Comment: No, the client has no magic ability to make the provider speak a protocol that it doesn't enable.  If you want to use AMQP then you need to enable AMQP.

Comment: sigh - I thought as much. A while back, we suggested AMQP but the service provider rejected it.

Comment: Why not use a C++ client that speaks the enabled protocol?

Comment: Because we don't know what the protocol is! It's ok - I've got an agreement with the service provider now so I think we're good. Turns out that the vendors they're choosing from all have a C++ client. Thanks for your help Tim.